# Creating Slack Bot to Answer Request

Tags: python, slack-api

I would like to create a Slack bot to answer some simple question or perform some task on the server. Here is what I have tried

```
token = "i-put-my-bot-token-here"      # found at https://api.slack.com/#auth)
sc = SlackClient(token)

sc.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel="magic", text="Hello World!")
```

It was posted as the Slackbot and not the bot account that I created?

Also if I were to listen the message, according to the python library it says

```
if sc.rtm_connect():
    while True:
        print sc.rtm_read()
        time.sleep(1)
else:
    print "Connection Failed, invalid token?"
```

Or should I use incoming webhook instead?

Answer (score 4):

As you can see [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) this call accepts an argument 'as_user' which can be true. If you set it as true, messages will be posted as the bot you created.

Answer (score 4):

I'm in the middle of creating a bot right now as well. I found that if you specified `as_user='true'`, it would post as you, the authed user. If you want it to be your bot, pass in the name of our bot and other options like emoji's like so:

```
sc.api_call(
    'chat.postMessage',
    username='new_slack_bot',
    icon_emoji=':ghost:',
    as_user='false',
    channel='magic',
    text='Hello World!'
)
```

Check [emoji cheat sheet](http://www.emoji-cheat-sheet.com/) for more.

Then, if you want to listen to events, like questions or commands, try intercepting the messages that are sent in. Example found on [this post](https://medium.com/@julianmartinez/how-to-write-a-slack-bot-end-to-end-d6a8542c854b):

```
while True:
    new_evts = sc.rtm_read()
    for evt in new_evts:
      print(evt)
      if "type" in evt:
        if evt["type"] == "message" and "text" in evt:    
          message=evt["text"]
          # write operations below to receive commands and respond as you like
```